# Using HashTables in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, hashtable

I have a large amount of text from which I need to find the most recurring words. I was thinking of using a hash table for that. 
Issue is, I obtain this text by using a JavaScript API and I am a newbie at that. Is it a good idea to create hash tables in JS and do all of this or will that be very inefficient?

I come from C++/Java, so it's fairly easy to do it there, but the API I'm using is easier in JS.

Comment: *will that be very inefficient*. That depends on your code, but Hash Tables (objects) are core to everything that Javascript does so you *will* be using them no matter what

Comment: Based on the answers below, it seems I'm using each key as an object property. Does this eliminate the need for hash function since there won't be a collision?
And is it a bad practice for memory management if I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript objects.

```js
var myHash = {};
var textArr = ["Mango","Apple","Orange","Grapes","Orange","Apple","Apple"];
textArr.forEach(function(fruit){ 
  if(myHash.hasOwnProperty(fruit)){
    myHash[fruit]++; 
  } 
  else { 
    myHash[fruit] = 1; } 
});
alert(JSON.stringify(myHash));
```